# SQL, joining the same table

Tags: sql, join, self-join

I have a `table` with the columns `code` and `document`. The column `code` may have alphanumeric values (only letters) and/or numeric values (only digits). In the model, every numeric `code` has an alphanumeric equivalent `code`. The records below represent an example of this situation (in the form (`document`,`code`);(`document`,`code`):

`(12345678900,ABC);(12345678900,999)`

But, a alphanumeric `code` may not always have a equivalent numeric `code`, so the example below represents a situation where we have 3 different records

`(12345678900,ABC);(12345678900,999);(00987654321,XYZ);(11111111111,DEF)`

With this in mind, what I want to do is the following: what I'll use to search records is always alphanumeric `code`s, and when I have an equivalent numeric, I want as result the numeric one, but when the alpha doesn't have the numeric equivalent, I want the alphanumeric `code`.

For instance, if I execute the following selects, I would get the results below:

1. `SELECT code FROM table WHERE code = 'ABC'` -> Result: 999
2. `SELECT code FROM table WHERE code = 'DEF'` -> Result: DEF
3. `SELECT code FROM table WHERE code = 'XXX'` -> Result: (blank)

I appreciate if anybody could help me please.

Regards,

AMR

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
    f1.doc
    , COALESCE(f2.code, f1.code) code
FROM foo f1
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT doc, code
    FROM foo
    WHERE code <> @code
) f2 ON f2.doc = f1.doc
WHERE f1.code = @code
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5af6d/14)